# Как очистить панель во второй форме?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как очистить `panelSetting` в форме `FormSetting` при нажатии на кнопку в `FormMain`

Вроде бы везде установил `Public` но не выходит, ошибка о необходимости ссылки на объект.

Comment: У Вас в коде где-то есть `FormSetting formSetting ...`. Используйте `formSetting.panelSetting.Controls.Clear();`

Comment: Тогда бы `FormSetting` был черным цветом, а так он указывает на то, что наименование формы с большой буквы существует.

Comment: В подчеркнутой строчке кода на картинке `FormSetting` это тип. Вам нужна ссылка на объект.

Comment: Я не знаю как создать ссылку на объект, в гугле слишком сложные примеры.

Comment: @Vitokhv вы ее **уже** где-то создали, теперь вам надо найти ее в своем же коде

Answer (score 2):

У Вас где-то должен быть код, который запускает форму `FormSettings`. Он должен быть примерно таким:

```
FormSettings formSettings;
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formSettings = new FormSettings();
    formSettings.Show();
}
```

Для очистки `panelSetting` можно написать:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (formSettings != null)
        formSettings.panelSettings.Controls.Clear();
}
```

Comment: В коде, даже в новом проекте нет строки `FormSettings formSettings;` где ее искать?

Comment: Откуда она может быть в новом проекте? Эту форму и панель на ней должны вы добавить. Или я что-то не понимаю? Вы писали _Подскажите, как очистить panelSetting в форме FormSetting_, то есть у Вас должна быть форма `FormSetting`, на котором есть `panelSetting`, которого Вы хотите очистить.

Comment: Пересоздал вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692914/