# Как очистить панель в главной форме, через другую форму?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Есть пример вопроса на видео** (см. ниже).

Подскажите, как очистить `panelMain` в главной форме `FormMain` при нажатии на кнопку в `FormSetting`.
Проблема в том, что стирать панель можно только через кнопки в главной форме.

Код который стирает панель через кнопки внутри главной формы:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form f2;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelMain.Controls.Clear();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelMain.Controls.Clear();

        if (f2 == null)
        {
            f2 = new FormSetting();
            f2.TopLevel = false;
            f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        panelMain.Controls.Add(f2);
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

Код со второй формы `FormSetting`, который не работает при сворачивании приложения. Появляется ошибка: `"Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."` в строках `Application.OpenForms`:

```
    private Form f1;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.OpenForms["FormMain"].Controls["panelMain"].Controls.Clear();

        if (f1 == null)
        {
            f1 = new FormGuid();
            f1.TopLevel = false;
            f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        Application.OpenForms["FormMain"].Controls["panelMain"].Controls.Add(f1);
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Видео пример: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y99ENUpMlOc

Comment: Это обычная задача коммуникации двух объектов. Обычное решение — один из классов должен выставить публичный метод, а второй — его вызвать.

Comment: Я могу ориентироваться только на примерах... предлагали использовать `Application.OpenForms[имя формы]` но не пойму как, и подходит ли такой способ.

Comment: Способ `Application.OpenForms` работает, но при сворачивании приложения появляется ошибка: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в метод открытия формы добавить:

```
f2.Tag = this;
```

То есть, получается следующее:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelMain.Controls.Clear();

    if (f2 == null)
    {
        f2 = new FormSetting();
        f2.TopLevel = false;
        f2.Tag = this;
        f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    panelMain.Controls.Add(f2);
    f2.Show();
}
```

А из формы `FormSetting` можно обращаться к главной форме как `(Tag as FormMain)`:

```
private Form f1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (Tag as FormMain).panelMain.Controls.Clear();
    if (f1 == null)
    {
        f1 = new FormGuid();
        f1.TopLevel = false;
        f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;       
    }
    (Tag as FormMain).panelMain.Controls.Add(f1);
    f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, первая команда вроде прошла, а вот вторая не хочет... говорит об ошибке ссылки на объект `(Tag as FormMain).Controls.Add(f1);`

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ. Таким образом у меня все работает.

Comment: Спасибо, я почему то пропустил `panelMain` в строчке... теперь работает. Еще поменял `private void` на `protected void` и выставил защиту для панели `Protected Internal` думаю немного защитит панель...

Comment: Не могли бы Вы еще подсказать, как работает `Tag = this;`. Просто у приложения будет несколько кнопок для отображения других форм, не будут ли они конфликтовать?

Comment: Tag - это свойство формы типа object, this - в этом случае `FormMain`. 
Вы можете добавить на форму `FormSetting` своё свойство и туда передавать `FormMain`. 
То есть,  на `FormSetting` добавляем: `public FormMain FrmMain { get; set; }`. 
Строку `private Form f2;` меняем на `private FormSetting f2;`
Строку `f2.Tag = this;` меняем на `f2.FrmMain = this;`